# Violating static function in C

Tags: c, static

In one interview I was asked, if in one file A, some static function is defined and in file B you want to use this static function -- how you will use it?

My answers were:

1. declaring in .h file
   But if we declare that in a header file, other files which will include this also have access to this static function.
2. wrapper concept: Declaring a new function `newfun` in file A, which will call static function and calling this `newfun` in file B.

But he was not satisfied with these answers.

Can you please provide me some better solution to violate `static`.

Comment: "Can you please provide me some better solution to violate STATIC ." Simple answer: **do not**! If this is how that company works, you should be happy not to get a job there.

Comment: then what is the purpose of making the function static in first place?

Comment: *By removing the keyword static* :p

Comment: perhaps they want to unit test it from a separate test file?

Comment: Hi Sourav, I know then the purpose of Static will be lost. But like constant variables are accessed through pointers i.e anonymous access ,Similar way static functions can also be :)

Comment: tell him he can dereference null pointer. when he says it's stupid tell him "so is violating static"..

Comment: but then you would need to compile both together . Its better declaring  header and including it and that's what is normally done.

Comment: Perhaps they wanted to hear about function pointers?

Comment: @shaina: So you provide a wrapper with external linkage? What would be the advantage over directly providing the original function? Ahh, yes, the wrapper would make everything more complicated and the system slower.

Comment: @SouravGhosh: whie typing a comment,Actually function pointer thing came to my mind ,Let me try :) I hope function pointers can provide the anonymous access to static fucntions.

Comment: @ThomasPadron-McCarthy: Great: using a global variable to expose a local function instead of the function itself. Well, that would not be the first dumb interview question - nor the last.

Comment: @Olaf: It doesn't have to be a global variable. One possible scenario is a callback function that you don't want to be callable by everyone, and you send the pointer to some register_callback function.

Comment: @ameyCU:  The disadvantage of header will be other files which are including this header can also access this.

Comment: @ThomasPadron-McCarthy : Yes Thomas you are right . smae thing now came to my mind .

Comment: I'll write it as an answer.

Comment: `#include` file A from file B, even if A is a "source" file. You'll get one definition rule hell but it does bring the static function into scope (which will not itself cause you ODR headaches). `extern static` *might* work on a broken compiler: that's not standard C. Perhaps the (rather unskilled) interviewer has such a tool.

Comment: @ThomasPadron-McCarthy: But you have to expose the register function. Anyway, this sound like a nonsense function. (If it was for a callback,then the question should have gotten into that direction. As given, it sounds like exposing a normal function, while a callback is an asynchronous thing and requires much more caution for the whole design.

Comment: Using a `static` function is by no means a "violation" of anything. It only means that the name of that function isn't accessible from outside. The function itself might well be.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Perhaps they wanted to hear about function pointers?

You can create a pointer to the function, and call it using that pointer.

One possible scenario where this is reasonable is if you have a callback function that you don't want to be callable by everyone, and you give the pointer as an argument to some `register_callback` function.

Callback functions were used extensively, for example to let the user of a GUI API provide code for what should happen when a button is pressed. Nowadays, with object-oriented languages, it is more common to subclass a class and define or override methods, such as the Android `View` class and the method `OnClickListener`, but C# delegates are very similar to C function pointers.

To illustrate the principle, here is the source code (the file "B" in the original question) for some sort of library, where the main component is the `do_stuff` function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "some_library.h"

void (*stored_callback)(void) = NULL;

void register_callback(void (*callback)(void)) {
    stored_callback = callback;
}

void do_stuff(void) {
    printf("Doing stuff...\n");
    printf("Calling callback...\n");
    if (stored_callback != NULL)
        stored_callback();
}
```

This header, `some_library.h`, file shows the API of that library:

```
extern void register_callback(void (*callback)(void));
extern void do_stuff(void);
```

And here is how the library is used (the file "A" in the question):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "some_library.h"

static void my_callback(void) {
    printf("Inside the callback!\n");
}

int main(void) {
    register_callback(my_callback);
    do_stuff();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How would you determine the address of the function you want to call though?

Comment: The question of @AndrewHenle is interesting. At compile time, the place where the linker will put the module A (that contains foo) is not known. I am not saying taht you cannot register it in some callback dispatcher, but you need to do it only in file A, and the question is, how is this handled by the compiler? what is the address of foo to register?? I guess it is relative to the module? or, in some way or another, something about foo will need to be available to the linker?...

Comment: @AndrewHenle and A.S.H: I added an example to try to illustrate how it works.

Comment: Yes, but in the original question, the function you're calling `my_callback()` is in *another file* and is not visible.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: No, as I understand it, `my_callback()` is in A, and it is then called from B.

Comment: Yes it is feasible, of course. I was just wondering what is the parameter the compiler sends to the `register_callback`. But then I realized that it should apply the same mechanism that it applies to any call to  `my_callback` inside file B. It uses some sort of relative addressing to compute the address of `my_callback`.

Answer (score 8):

My interview answer would be "You can't."

(Because the question says "in file B you want to use this *static* function" and it didn't say you are allowed to modify file A.)

Comment: My Answer would probably be "Presuming I cannot access or modify source of file b, you cannot."

Comment: I'd think this is the only strictly correct answer, because the `static` keyword means the function simply isn't visible per the C standard outside the file it's defined in.  While a compiler *may* emit a symbol for the function in a way that can be hacked, it doesn't have to do that and is likely free to inline the function entirely.  Some ot the other answers may work perfectly fine with specific compilers and/or linkers, but there's no requirement that they do.

Comment: No, `static` only means that the name of the function isn't visible to the outside. As other answers show a pointer to the function can well be exported to the outer world.

Comment: The fact that it isn't visible means the compiler isn't required to emit something that a function pointer can even point to.  It *may* do that, and the answers that use a function pointer do rely on that behavior.  But it doesn't *have to*.  Try using a very high optimization level when compiling C code with a short static function - for example, one that calculates the product of two complex numbers.  Most compilers will *inline* such a function and it won't exist as a separate entity in the emitted binary object.

Comment: @Jens-Gustedt, if a pointer to the function is exported in one or another way, the compiler will no longer in-line the function. This also means modifying file A, and hence the solution should then be to remove the `static` keyword. All other pointer stuff is then useless. If this is about a call-back function, then the `register_callback` function should be in file A and then the static function can remain static. Adding `register_callback` is again modifying file A, hence this is not about a callback. Conclusion: "You can't."

Comment: @AndrewHenle, you are just wrong. *If* you take the address of a `static` function and propagate it to the outer world, the compiler *must* realize the function and provide you with that.  And by the way, the question nowhere states that the files can't be modified, that is just an arbitrary assumption that you are making.

Comment: @JensGustedt What is the point of exporting a visible, non-static function pointer if you can modify the file? **Just remove the `static` keyword**. And if you **can't** modify the source code there's no way to guarantee access to a `static` function in that file.  **Without making any assumptions the original question of how to call a static function in another compilation unit can not in general be solved.**  Note **you** have to **assume** "*If* you take the address of a `static` function and propagate that to the outer world ..."  You make unsupported assumptions and call me wrong?

Comment: @AndrewHenle, why are you shouting at me? Because I said you are wrong? I don't make assumptions, this just how this works. Exporting pointers of `static` functions is a common technique, and the C standard provides the means for it. If you have several variants of functions do a job and you have to dynamically choose one of them, this is a technique that avoids polluting the name space and gets the job done. This also something that you would do to use the C library functions `bsearch` and `qsort`: make the comparison function `static` so it doesn't create name conflicts with other TU.

Comment: @JensGustedt The original question does not state that you can *assume* "*If* you take the address of a `static` function and propagate it to the outer world". That's an *assumption*.  It doesn't matter what the technique of taking an address of a `static` function is used for, because - again - the original question doesn't state that something in the original code takes the address of the `static` function in question. The only way to solve the original problem is to make assumptions. You have to assume you can modify the file, you have to assume a symbol is emitted, etc.

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you don't have access to the source of the static function or else you could just remove the `static` keyword or expose the function via an exported wrapper or global function pointer.

You can still use the static function if you use `objcopy` to manually change the visibility on the symbol in the object file / library.

Suppose this is the (unaccessible) static function:

```
//static.c
#include <stdio.h>
static void fun(){
  puts("Hello world");
}
```

Suppose you only have `static.o`, obtainable with `gcc -c static.c`.

Now, let's assume you want to link `static.o` with `main.o` made from

```
//main.c
void fun();

void main(){
  fun();
};
```

To be able to link it, you need to turn

```
$ nm static.o
0000000000000000 t fun
                 U puts
```

into

```
0000000000000000 T fun
                U puts
```

You can do that with:

```
objcopy --globalize-symbol=fun static.o global.o
```

Now you can link with `global.o` instead of `static.o`.

```
$ gcc main.o global.o && ./a.out
  Hello world
```

Comment: Ok, so now I have _seven_ answers to give if I ever go to an interview at that company.

Comment: Eight, if you count "use a debugger in a way God never intended".

Comment: IMO, this is a pretty clean build-system-level solution which actually solves a problem that doesn't exist if you can create a globally accessible pointer to the static function, because being able to create said pointer implies you have access to the source and can simply remove the static keyword.

Comment: That assumes the compiler creates a `fun` symbol in `static.o`.  It doesn't have to, much the same as the variable `i` in `void func(){ int i; ... }` doesn't have a symbol, yet in code *where `i` is visible* you can still take the address of `i` with `&i`.

Comment: @PSkocik: Yes, I agree that objcopy != gdb. Using gdb to call the function is a completely different solution from this one. That is why it was number eight, while yours was number seven.

Comment: Oh I see what you meant.

Answer (score 2):

filea.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "filea.h"
static void hidden(void) { printf("inside hidden function.\n"); }
fxptr unhide(void) { return hidden; }
```

filea.h

```
#ifndef FILEA_INCLUDED
#define FILEA_INCLUDED
typedef void(*fxptr)(void);
fxptr unhide(void);
#endif
```

fileb.c

```
#include "filea.h"
int main(void) {
    unhide()();
    return 0;
}
```